# Pubspec.yaml in Android Studio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wrocl.jpg)

What kind of mistakes are happening with me ?

Please somebody guide me

Comment: check your front spacing of your pubspec.yaml  `assets`, your asset must be equally with the `uses-material-design: true`, inside of pubspec.yaml spacing was a important. check this doc for more information

Answer (score 0):

Your error is from indentation since indentation is very important in Yaml as it is in Python.

1. assets should be on the same starting line with uses-material-design. Example below

```
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
```

Please post the code next time instead of a screenshot or you colud post both.

Answer (score 0):

**

```
Open Your project
Create an asset file in the project, go to pubspaec.yaml.
1. Comment out assets file add assets folder (left side 2 space) then get a pub gate.
```

**

[image]